# Has anyone seen my formula that approximates the number of primes up to n?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

For closed formulas, a formula that approximates the numbers of primes less than or equal to $n$ is $\dfrac{n}{\ln(n)}$.

A formula that gets much closer to the exact values, at least for $n < 3000$, is $\dfrac{n}{\ln(n) - 1}$.

I discovered $\dfrac{n}{\log_{10}(n^2)}$, which gives values many times within 2 of the actual value for $n < 3000$.

Has anyone seen my formula before?  (I looked for it on the Internet.)

Comment: $n<3000$ is not a rangle one is interested, really. For big $n$, the integral logarithm is much better.

Comment: For $n=10000$, we'll have $\dfrac{n}{\log_{10}(n^2)}=\dfrac{10000}{\log_{10}(100000000)}=1250$, while $\pi(10000)=1229$. And it will be still worse for larger values of $n$. What could primes possibly have to do with a logarithm with base $10$?!

Comment: @ Professor Vector - Your comment doesn't count, because you changed the subject and talked about a different range.  You see that I deliberately mentioned a lower range.  You must stick to the merits of the parameters of what I presented, not what you fancy the problem to be.

Answer (score 3):

Nice work! Yep, $\frac{n}{\ln n}$ in particular is the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem). The other two formulas, $\frac{n}{\ln(n) - 1}$ and $\frac{n}{\log_{10}(n^2)}$, look like over-fitting to small values. Note that $\log_{10}(n^2)=2\log_{10}(n)=\frac{2}{\ln 10}\ln(n)\approx 0.868\ln(n)$. So that formula will be off by a constant factor for very large $n$.

Comment: Please, read a question before answering. Thank you!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: For $n=10000$, we'll have $\dfrac{n}{\log_{10}(n^2)}=\dfrac{10000}{\log_{10}(100000000)}=1250$, while $\pi(10000)=1229$. And it will be still worse for larger values of $n$. What could primes possibly have to do with a logarithm with base $10$?!

Comment: @ProfessorVector Oh, that's not what I meant. Let me clarify the answer.

Comment: Oh, clarify as much as you can, certainly. Will it still be an answer to the question the OP asked, though?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Look, I was assuming OP meant that "my formula" referred to the set of all three formulas, since they didn't mention that they were aware of the prime number theorem. In retrospect I was probably wrong with that assumption, but it's not productive for you to be so confrontational in pursuing the point.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Somebody forgot their coffee. Done turned into a goat.

Answer (score 2):

Your approximation is

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{n}{\log_{10}(n^2)}
&=\dfrac{n}{2\log_{10}n}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{2\ln(n)/\ln(10)}\\
&=\dfrac{\ln 10}{2}\dfrac{n}{\ln(n)}\\
&\approx 1.15\dfrac{n}{\ln(n)}\\
\end{array}
$

which is about
15% high for large $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If you look [on Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeNumberTheorem.html), you will find some formulas that look a lot like yours. Specifically Equation $1$: $$\pi(n) \sim \frac{n}{\log n + B}$$ with $B = -1.08366$, which, as it turns out, is very close to your $B = -1$ (I like to use "$\log$" instead of $\ln$").

Have you studied calculus, at least cursorily? The prime number theorem is an excellent example of the concept of a limit. With $B = 0$, the formula gets more accurate as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: @ Mr. Brooks - This site appears to be one of the places that you are referencing:  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeCountingFunction.html

Comment: @ Ms. Stemfom Oh yes, that one too. Anything from Mathworld is good.